# Add XElement that uses namespace

Tags: c#

I create a XDocument with namespaces in my constructor e.g.

```
this.nsXsl = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
 this.doc = new XDocument(
               new XElement(nsXsl + "stylesheet", new XAttribute("version", "1.0"), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"),
               new XElement(nsXsl + "output", new XAttribute("method", "xml"), new XAttribute("indent", "yes"), new XAttribute("encoding", "UTF-8")),
               new XElement(nsXsl + "strip-space", new XAttribute("elements", "*")))
               );
```

This document has the right structure and looks like I want.

But I have a function like:

```
private XElement createTemplate(string match, string node, string fork, string select)
        {
            return new XElement(this.nsXsl + "template", new XAttribute("match", match), new XElement(node,
                new XElement(this.nsXsl + fork, new XAttribute("select", select))));

        }
```

this function returns a XElement of the following structure:

```
<template match="/shiporder/shipto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Line1>
    <apply-templates select="city" xmlns="" />
  </Line1>
</template>
```

But I need a XElement like:

```
<xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipto">
  <Line1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="city" />
  </Line1>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The change you want is only cosmetic, and how/when is the new XElement attached to the XDoc?

Comment: @HenkHolterman till now I have a list of templates and will add them like `   foreach (XElement elem in templates)
            {
                doc.Add(elem);
            }`

Comment: Then the problem will resolve itself. Don't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points. First, your `Line1` element is qualified with a namespace and `apply-templates` is not, while what you want is the reverse. That's your own doing: you add namespace in `new XElement(this.nsXsl + node, …` (`node`, I presume, is `"Line1"`), and you omit to do so in `new XElement(fork, …` (obviously, `fork` is `"apply-templates"`). Just move `this.nsXsl +` from former to the latter spot.

Second, you say you'd prefer that XSLT namespace be denoted by a prefix, `xsl`. Binding between a prefix and namespace is set by declaration expressed in the form of an attribute of a special form, `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + prefix, namespaceUri)` (you actually do that in your first code snippet). This binding is valid in the element where it is declared and all nested elements, unless overset by another declaration. When XML writer emits an element with a namespace-qualified name, it detects that that namespace is bound to a prefix and uses that prefix (e. g., in your first code snippet, namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` is bound to prefix `xsl`, so XML writer adds the `xsl:` prefix to all nested elements). If XML writer finds out that a used namespace is not bound to a prefix, it emits the default namespace declaration attribute, `xmlns="namespace"` for you (note that default namespace only affects elements, not attributes).

From the viewpoint of XML information model, the following three snippets are equivalent:

```
<template match="/shiporder/shipto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Line1 xmlns="">
    <apply-templates select="city" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" />
  </Line1>
</template>

<xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipto" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Line1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="city" />
  </Line1>
</template>

<weird:template match="/shiporder/shipto" xmlns:weird="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Line1>
    <weird:apply-templates select="city" />
  </Line1>
</template>
```

Comment: I agree in the first point. For second point you mentioned to add "xsl:" in front of my tag names is only possible by adding `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + prefix, namespaceUri)` to my XElement?

Comment: @StellaMaris, exactly. Just as it was done in your first code snippet.

Comment: Is it possible to use `XName nodeName = this.nsXsl + "template"; XElemnet e=this.doc.Element(nodeName);` some how?

Comment: @StellaMaris, Perfectly.